# How to hide headers and footers in Micrsoft Word 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, microsoft-word-2011, page-layout-view, footers

I'm using Microsoft Word 2011 for Macintosh on OSX Mountain Lion and when viewing my document in `Print Layout` mode, I would like to hide the header and footers so that the text at the bottom of one page rolls right into the text of the following page with no space for headers, footers, or a page break.

How can I hide the headers and footers?  Do I need to switch to a different viewing mode other than `Print Layout`?  On windows version of word I was using, I would just double click on the blank area between pages, above the header of the next page and below the footer of the current page to hide them, but this does not work on my Macintosh. I tried `Draft` mode, but I don't like that you do not see the edges of the paper anymore and you lose and notes from the margins in that mode.